# What do you call a subject open for doctoral studies?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, terminology

Universities generally have a set of subjects open for doctoral studies. In my own language we call them "forskarutbildningsämnen", which translates as "doctoral education subjects". Now I'm wondering what would be the most common/idiomatic equivalent in BrE – in translations from my own language to English the most common by far is "third-cycle subject", but I have come to understand that this is not widely understood by people in general? Among the alternatives I have thought of myself (PhD subject, doctoral subject, doctoral education subject, and research training subject), it seems that the most common is "PhD subject", followed by "doctoral subject" (using Google Ngram), but perhaps there is another word that I just haven't thought of that is more common? Also, if PhD subject is, indeed, the alternative most commonly used, I'm wondering whether it can still be used about **all** doctoral education – not only about the kind that leads to a degree of doctor of philosophy?

Note that by "subject" I mean the overall subjects/subject areas within which doctoral students can conduct their studies. For instance, English, comparative literature, physics and so on. So, not the specific topics that a certain doctoral student can write their thesis on.

Comment: [Examples of PhD thesis topics](https://www.educ.cam.ac.uk/people/doctoralstudents/) (Cambridge university)

Comment: @Graffito Oh, this makes me realise I wasn't clear in my OP; I meant the overall subjects, like English, comparative literature, physics and so on. So, subject rather than topic :)

Comment: Do you mean [fields_of_doctoral_studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fields_of_doctoral_studies_in_the_United_States) ?

Comment: There isn't any official term (common of English) but I believe that "areas of active research" captures the idea.

Comment: I speak American English and the term "discipline" seems apt, but it has broader application than just to doctoral studies.

Comment: In the UK, universities offer "PhD program(me)s" by department (so you could ask "what PhD programs does Imperial College offer?"). "PhD subject" is also common, although it could refer to the specific topic. There's also Academia SE.

Comment: Thank you so much all of you for your input! Much appreciated!